# Minimizing $|x_1-x_2|+|x_2-x_3|$ given two conditions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, optimization, arithmetic-progressions

> Let $x_1, x_2, x_3 \in \Bbb R$, satisfy $0 \leq x_1 \leq x_2 \leq x_3 \leq 4$. If their squares form an arithmetic progression with common difference $2$, determine the minimum possible value of $$|x_1-x_2|+|x_2-x_3|$$

---

So far, I've started with the fact $x_2^2 - x_1^2 = x_3^2 - x_2^2 = 2$ since we know their squares form an arithmetic progression with common difference $2.$ We can solve this to obtain

$$x_2 = \pm\sqrt{x_1^2+2}, \qquad x_3 = \pm\sqrt{x_1^2+4}$$

I'm not sure how to continue. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: It's probably easier to change variables $y_j = x_j^2$, so that $2\le y_2 \le 14$ and (WLOG) $y_1 = y_2-2$ and $y_3=y_2+2$, so that we are trying to minimize $(\sqrt{y_2}-\sqrt{y_2-2}) + (\sqrt{y_2+2}-\sqrt{y_2})$.

Comment: Any help or any ways to continue on where I started off?

Comment: This should help $|x_1-x_2|+|x_2-x_3|=x_3-x_1$.

Comment: do i just do $\pm\sqrt{x_1^2+4}\pm\sqrt{x_1^2+2}$ then? Also, how did you reduce that to $x_3-x_1?$

Comment: The $0\leq x_1\leq x_2 \leq x_3\leq 4$ is a very valuable information, try doing it yourself and if you are still stuck I'll write a solution.

Comment: Ok I think I have the answer now. We can let $x_3=4$ because this would clearly produce the minimum value possible. This implies we have $x_1^2=12$ and $x_2^2=14.$ We can compute to get our quantity as $4-2\sqrt{3}.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that:

$$x_3 - x_1 = \dfrac{x_3^2-x_1^2}{x_3+x_1} = \dfrac{4}{\sqrt{x_1^2+4}+x_1}$$
and this is obviously minimized at the largest possible value of $x_1.$ That value is obtained by observing:
$$16\geq x_3^2 = x_1^2+4\iff x_1\leq\sqrt{12}$$
and so the minimum is $\dfrac{4}{4+\sqrt{12}} = 4-\sqrt{12}.$

Answer (score 0):

[image]

( vertical scale compressed )

A way to see this intuitively is to consider the parabolic curve $ \ y \ = \ x^2 \ \ . $  We are to choose three values of $ \ x \ $ so that the *vertical* spacings of their points on the curve are $ \ 2 \ $ units apart.  We see that since the parabola becomes "steeper" as $ \ x \ > \ 0 \ $ increases, the total spacing $ \ x_3 - x_1 \ $ *decreases*.  So we would want to have our three values of $ \ x \ $ be as large as possible in the interval, which means setting $ \ x_3 \ = \ 4 \ \ , $ for which we then must have $ \ x_2 \ =  \ \sqrt{14} \ $ and $ \ x_1 \ = \ \sqrt{12} \ \ . $

We can estimate the required spacing by using the slope formula $ \ m \ = \ \frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x} \ \ : \ $ at a particular value of $ \ x \ \ , $ we take the nearby points $ \ x \ \pm \ \delta \ $ to write
$$ m \ \ \approx \ \ \frac{(x + \delta)^2 \ - \  (x - \delta)^2}{(x + \delta) \ - \ (x - \delta)} \ \ = \ \ \frac{4·\delta·x}{2 · \delta} \ \ = \ \ 2·x \ \ . $$
The spacing between $ \ x_{i} \ $ and $ \ x_{i+1} \ $ will then be about
$ \ x_{i+1}  -  x_{i} \ = \ \frac{\Delta y}{m} \ = \  \frac{2}{2·x_{i}} \ = \ \frac{1}{x_{i}} \ \ , $ indicating that the spacing between $ \ x-$values will be "tighter" as $ \ x \ $ increases.  For purposes of comparison, with $ \ x_3 \ = \ 3 \ \ , $ we have roughly $ \ x_3 - x_1 \ = \ \frac{1}{\sqrt5} \ + \ \frac{1}{\sqrt7} \ \approx \ 0.825 \ \ , $ while for $ \ x_3 \ = \ 4 \ \ ,  \ x_3 - x_1 \ = \ \frac{1}{\sqrt{12}} \ + \ \frac{1}{\sqrt{14}} \ \approx \ 0.556 \ \ . $   This confirms our geometrical intuition.

Naturally, the precise answer is derived from the method used by **dezdichado**.